# Is it possible to add client authentication certificate (.pfx) to Web Activities in Data Factory using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I want to add client authentication certificate (.pfx) to Web Activities in Data Factory. Certificate needs to be fetched from Azure key vault.

Right now this is done manually.

I want to automate the same , is it possible to do using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to automate the same , is it possible to do using powershell.

Yes, we could use [Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/set-azurermdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azurermps-6.8.1) to add the client authentication certificate.

The following is the detail steps, you could refer to

1.Create a web-activity definition json , for more information please refer to [control-flow-web-activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)

2.Get the pfx file from keyvault, the pfx file get from keyvault is that without password. So we need to add the password to the pfx

```
$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName
$kvSecretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($kvSecret.SecretValueText)
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
$certCollection.Import($kvSecretBytes,$null,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$password = '******'
$protectedCertificateBytes = $certCollection.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)
$pfxPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\MyCert.pfx"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pfxPath, $protectedCertificateBytes)
```

3.Update the json file with pfx value and password

4.Run the set-AzureRmDataFactory command

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup" -Name "name" -DataFactoryName "factoryName" -File "C:\webactivity.json"
```